# BigQuery User Defined Aggregation Function?

Tags: google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, udf

I know I can define a [User Defined Function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) in order to perform some custom calculation. I also know I can use the 'out-of-the-box' [aggregation functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#aggregate-functions) to reduce a collection of values to a single value when using a `GROUP BY` clause.

Is it possible to define a custom user-defined, Aggregation Function to use with a `GROUP BY` clause?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Turns out that this IS possible (as long as the groups we seek to aggregate are of a reasonable size in memory) with a  little bit of 'glue' - namely the `ARRAY_AGG` function

The steps are as follows:

1. Create a UDF with an input parameter of type `ARRAY<T>` where `T` is the type of value you want to aggregate.
2. Use the `ARRAY_AGG` function in the query with the `GROUP BY` clause to generate an array of `T` and pass into your UDF.

As a concrete example:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION aggregate_fruits(fruits ARRAY<STRING>)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
return "my fruit bag contains these items: " + fruits.join(",");
""";

WITH fruits AS
(SELECT "apple" AS fruit
UNION ALL SELECT "pear" AS fruit
UNION ALL SELECT "banana" AS fruit)

SELECT aggregate_fruits(ARRAY_AGG(fruit))
FROM fruits
```

Comment: For others, here is the associated feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62898282