# Define Permanent User Defined Function in BigQuery for aggregating results

Tags: google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, user-defined-functions, permanent

I have used this sample code to write functions on the aggregated data from Big Query.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION aggregate_fruits(fruits ARRAY<STRING>)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE js AS """
return "my fruit bag contains these items: " + fruits.join(",");
""";

WITH fruits AS
(SELECT "apple" AS fruit
UNION ALL SELECT "pear" AS fruit
UNION ALL SELECT "banana" AS fruit)

SELECT aggregate_fruits(ARRAY_AGG(fruit))
FROM fruits;
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974448/bigquery-user-defined-aggregation-function) has been used as a reference. But the query is taking more time in order to first define the function and then run the query. Is it possible to define the function only once and then use the same function for multiple queries ?

BigQuery says this error when I tried removing "TEMP" keyword from the above

```
Error: Only temporary functions are currently supported; use CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION
```

Comment: How do you know that it's taking more time?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard ran CREATE TEMP FUNCTION and  select "user" as user both. The select query is nothing it is running in millisecond but with the CREATE TEMP it is running in 6 seconds.

Comment: It's due to initializing the JavaScript environment, which will happen even if the SELECT statement doesn't call the UDF.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard you are absolutely correct. That's why I am curious to know if I can defined my function once and run multiple queries using that function. As of now I can run only one query from the dashboard. If I want to run it again, I again need to initialise the function again which I don't want. Can you share some thoughts ?

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905921) that you may want to follow for permanent UDFs. It's not going to reduce the overhead of using JavaScript UDFs, however.

Comment: Thanks @ElliottBrossard Initialising it once is fine. I am worried about it getting it initialised every time I run a new query which uses the same function defined.